# How do I count distinct values based on a non-primary key filter in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cql

relational databases and Cassandra. With two tables like the following:

TABLE 1: PRIMARY KEY (ID, DATE));

| ID | DATE | TRIP_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B03291 | 2022-01-01 | 5 |
| B03291 | 2022-01-02 | 6 |
| ZR7875 | 2022-01-01 | 2 |
| ZR7875 | 2022-01-02 | 0 |

TABLE 2: PRIMARY KEY ((ID, TYPE), DATE))

| TYPE | ID | DATE | TRIP_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B03291 | 2022-01-01 | 5 |
| A | B03291 | 2022-01-02 | 6 |
| B | ZR7875 | 2022-01-01 | 2 |
| B | ZR7875 | 2022-01-02 | 0 |
| A | GF4589 | 2022-01-01 | 7 |

The two tables have the same data but aggregated in a different way.

Using the table that suits better for this query, I need to get the COUNT of all the IDs that have a trip_time greater than 0 on the DATE = '2022-01-01', but I can´t use allow filtering or create another table.

I have been using the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID)
FROM table1
WHERE date = '2022-01-01'
AND trip_time > 0;
```

But it raises an error and asks me to allow filtering. If I can´t specify an ID, because I want the COUNT for all, is there any way to do this?

Thank you for your help and sorry if it is too obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Cause

You are getting this error because your query doesn't have a filter on primary key columns:

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] \
  message="Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have \
  unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the performance \
  unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING"
```

Neither the trip date nor the trip time are primary key columns for the tables so it is not possible to query using these columns.

#### Warning

The `ALLOW FILTERING` clause enables filtering on non-primary key columns by performing a full table scan, querying every single partition on all nodes so it is very expensive and unpredictable.

The `ALLOW FILTERING` clause is only recommended for use when the query is restricted to a single partition.

#### Workaround

In order to query against non-primary key columns, you need to index the columns. To illustrate with an example, here's my table which has the trip `id` as the primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE stackoverflow.trips_by_id (
    id text PRIMARY KEY,
    tripdate date,
    triptime int
)
```

If I want to run queries using either `tripdate` or `triptime`, I need to index these columns with:

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX tripdate_idx ON stackoverflow.trips_by_id (tripdate);
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX triptime_idx ON stackoverflow.trips_by_id (triptime);
```

Now that I have indexed them, I can execute queries like:

```
SELECT ... FROM trips_by_id
  WHERE tripdate = ?
  AND triptime = ?
```

WARNING: Be aware that indexing has its own issues so be aware of the pros and cons. Have a look at [When to use and not use an index](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_using/useWhenIndex.html) for details.

#### Solution

Cassandra is designed for high throughput, high velocity online transaction (OLTP) use cases where you are retrieving data one partition at a time (queries filtered by partition key).

In contrast, your query is analytics (OLAP) in nature because you are not reading just one partition -- you are scanning through the whole table. As such, the best way to run analytics queries is to use Apache Spark with the [Spark Cassandra connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector). Cheers!

---

Please support the Apache Cassandra community by hovering over the [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra) tag then click on the `Watch tag` button.  Thanks!

Comment: It finally worked, I needed to create the index as you pointed. Thank you